# loc get index without .index[0]

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-loc

I like to look up the value of the index of my DataFrame.

```
idxnumber=df.loc[(df['ID'] == i[1]) & (df['date'] ==i[0])]
```

With this Code I get the complete line of may DataFrame. My idea was just to add `.index[0]` at the end of my Code. But the problem is, that sometimes there is not row for the loc function and than I will run in an error.

I need the index as an integer because in the next step I like to subtract some values of this index.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Do you want to index by row number ? If that is the case you can use `.iloc` instead of `.loc` and pass the row number. But isn't it only logical for it to give an error of the index cannot be found ?

Comment: i want to look up the index for a certain row in my dataframe. So I thought with .loc i will get the right row and thann look at the index in the row

Comment: with .index.values i would get my index but it is in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this to get the value of the ID:

```
idxnumber=df.loc[(df['ID'] == i[1]) & (df['date'] ==i[0]), 'ID']
```

you  can get the index as well by:

```
df.loc[(df['ID'] == i[1]) & (df['date'] ==i[0]), 'ID'].index[0]
```

Comment: ID is not the index. ID is a column in ma dataframe. sorry the name is missleading

Comment: @pythoo Either way, you can pull one or more columns out by adding the column name in that position, does that help? Instead of the full line